# How does one create an Ender Crystal-summoning Eye of Ender

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Out of curiosity, and the want to use something similar in a map I'm creating, I want to create a system that essentially makes an Eye of Ender invisible, then causes it to summon Ender Crystals beneath it. For simplicity in not making Minecraft search vast areas of land for the crystals, I made a `minecraft.used:minecraft.ender_eye` scoreboard named `eyeUse`. My current system of commands to do this feat is this;

```
execute as @a at @s if score @s eyeUse matches 1 run effect give @e[type=minecraft:eye_of_ender] invisibility 9999 1 true
execute as @a at @s if score @s eyeUse matches 1 run summon minecraft:end_crystal ~ ~-1 ~
execute as @a at @s if score @s eyeUse matches 1 run scoreboard players reset @s eyeUse
```

However, this doesn't seem to be working. I've attempted to swap `as` and `at` (as I couldn't remember their order for scanning for all and then executing for one, but I believe my current is correct). The scoreboard is, in fact, increasing, and seeing as I've made similar command systems I'm confused as to why this isn't working. I'm using 1.13 Java Edition.

Comment: So you're saying that the last command doesn't actually reset the scoreboard correctly? Also, this looks like it would summon the crystal directly in your face, do you want that? And do you want the ender eye to disappear completely? In that case you could just kill it instead of making it invisible. Does the invisibility effect even work on it?

Comment: 1) Not only does it not reset the scoreboard, it doesn't even make the Eye invisible or summon the crystals. 2) In the context of my problem, no; I realize that that makes it summon under my feet, not at the Ender Eye's position. I can change that though. 3) No, I don't want the eye to completely vanish, because I want it to summon crystals along its path of flight. 4) Yes, because Ender Eyes have their own entity name while flying ("eye_of_ender").

Comment: Then the usual checks: Do you really have that score? Are your commands actually running? …

Comment: Yup. ``scoreboard players list`` tells me that I have the necessary score to start the commands, and the command blocks I'm using go Repeating-Chain-Chain (respectively, in order top-down in the question) and are set to Always Active.

Comment: What happens if you execute them one by one in chat?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but basically... nothing.

Comment: Then try leaving out the "if score @s eyeUse matches 1 " part.

Comment: @EarthToAccess This command `execute at @e[type=minecraft:eye_of_ender] run summon minecraft:end_crystal` summons ender crystals at the position of every ender eye. It doesn´t seem to be possible to make ender eyes invisible.